# How to sum time based on a given time in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class Clock(models.Model):
report_submitted_at = models.TimeField()
delivery_time = models.TimeField(null=True, Blank=True)
```

I am new to Django so I am curious how to achieve this. In my model report_submitted_at time I am entering.
Based on the entered time i want to save the delivery time automatically. Delivery time is always '04:00:00'. So suppose i entered report_submitted_time '02:00:00'. The delivery time will be '06:00:00' for that row.

I imported datetime. Manually i am able to add two times. But here how can i save the delivery time automatically. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django signals like this.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import models


@receiver(signal=models.signals.post_save, sender=Clock):
def set_delivery_time(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:  # For new objects, it will be True. In case of updating old object, it will be false
        instance.delivery_time = instance.report_submitted_at.replace(hour=instance.report_submitted_at.hour + 4)
        instance.save()
```

Comment: Thank You. It worked.

Comment: There is one small issue. When I type time between 20:00 to 23:59. It throws error - hour must be in 0..23

Comment: I added sample code. You can modify part where we are adding 4 hours in `report_submitted_at` time where you can set time according to `report_submitted_at`. If After adding 4 hour, it goes beyond 23:59, we start time from 00:00.